# Sharepoint 2013 updates

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

My client runs SharePoint 2013 with lastest version released in April 2014.  can I upgrade directly to the latest version / upgrade for SharePoint 2013, which is ﻿KB 4011251 (Released Nov 2017) or do I need to go through the upgrades one by one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For advice about the updates I always go to Stefan's blog. As you are on April 2014 it means you are on the Service Pack 1 which is required for that cumulative update. So you can go ahead and install it directly. SP updates are Cumulative from the service pack so no need to install any of the updates in between.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2017/11/14/november-2017-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-product-family-is-available-for-download/

As per blog above remember to run PSConfig after you complete patching. Another thing that you might need to update with the Sharepoint is application fabric (it is used by the Distributed Cache) latest CU for AppFabric is 7. You can check the version of the fabric via Installed Programs -->Windows updates